# opencl- Is there a way to reallocate local memory?

Tags: opencl

Is there a way to reallocate local memory in one same kernel

EX)

```
    __local float arr[size 1] //maximum size
    ..
     arr usage
    ..
    free arr
    __local float arr2[size 2] //smaller than size1
    arr2 usage
```

if i want use different purpose, should i reuse `arr` with different indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot dynamically reallocate memory in OpenCL.
You can define one or more `__local` arrays depending on their size of course as the local memory is limited.
You can also reuse previously defined array for other purpose.
If you need different array size per kernel call then you can pass local array as a kernel parameter and decide on the host which size should that be per each call.

Answer (score 0):

It's C99, so You could make a union of the structure or arrays you want to use sequentially. They would share the memory.